# Only able to use flag "Other"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

I just tried to flag a post, and the only option I had was "Other".

I can see the full set of options when flagging other posts (and I refreshed the page to check it hadn't loaded incorrectly), so it's unlikely to be something local to my computer. I have 31 helpful - 2 declined flags, so I also doubt it any sort of automatic block from flagging for whatever reason.

I can't find anything that mentions it and I don't know of any reason you would be allowed to flag, but not use the default options.

[image: Single flagging option]

Was there something I did that caused this? Or was it just a fluke/random bug of some form? Or even a feature I don't know about?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking around, [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226433/226203) indicates that this can happen when the review loads, and then the post is deleted. The review UI doesn't know about the deletion, so it doesn't tell you about it, but when you load the Flag Dialog, it contacts the server, which already knows that only the Other option is valid now.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Though I would have thought that if the page pulls the options (or whatever it's requesting that's returning null) down from the server and the post no longer exists, some form of error could easily be triggered in their place.

Comment: Not only for reviews. If any post is deleted, you can only flag it with "other".